# Ajax call success function duplicates the returned json

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In this code returned json from controller shows 5 items but it's duplicates in the ajax call success function.

Html

```
 <select class="form-control  id="books">
 </select>
```

My Ajax Call

```
  function LoadBooks(rackNo) {
    debugger;

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetBookDetails", "Books")',
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ rackNo: rackNo }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (_booklst) {
            debugger;

            console.log(_booklst);
                $('#books').empty();
                $.each(_booklst, function (index, item) {
                    $('#books').append($('<option><option/>').val(item.bookno).text(item.bookname));
                });

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem?

Comment: Because your controller method return 5 duplicate items.

Comment: Problem is _booklst has 5 items but when it bind to the dropdown list it bind 10 items.. each item duplicates.

Comment: @StephenMuecke No. it returns 5 items

Comment: Edit your question to explain the problem and show how you call the `LoadBooks()` function.

Comment: I think ajax call is getting book details, then why 'type: "POST"', if i am correct 'type' should be GET.

Comment: Or show us the returned JSON

Comment: @TechGuy, The only way the code you have shown can generate 10 options is if your controller method returns a collection containing 10 items (and if you add `console.log(_booklst.length);` you will see that the output is `10`)

Comment: What is the order of 10 output items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
$.each(_booklst, function (index, item) {
    $('#books').append($('<option><option/>').val(item.bookno).text(item.bookname));
});
```

to

```
$.each(_booklst, function (index, item) {
    $('#books').append($('<option></option>').val(item.bookno).text(item.bookname));
});
```

(the position of the  `/` in `'<option></option>'`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem. Use

`<select class="form-control"  id="books">  </select>`

instead of

```
 <select class="form-control  id="books">
 </select>
```

Comment: Other that the fact this will not work because of the missing `"` after `class="form-control`, what difference do you think this is supposed to make, and how does it solve OP's issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke In op's question he was missing ". I just corrected it

Comment: Yes, but that was just a typo in the question text and this answer does not address OP problem at all.